# C#: AsyncCallback not being called on Socket.BeginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a serious problem with the asynchronous Receive method of System.Net.Sockets.Socket.

Here is the code I use to open the connection:

```
_socket = new Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_socket.Connect(endpoint);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
_socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, buffer);
```

and here is the callback method:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
     byte[] buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
     int count = _socket.EndReceive(result);

     if (count > 0)
     {
          // Do something
     }

     buffer = new byte[1024];
     _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, buffer);
}
```

The problem is that the ReceiveCallback is never being called, despite the socket being connected.

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: Are you sure that there is data being sent to the socket? The callback method isn't called until data is received. (`count` will never be `0`.)

Comment: Ok, if data is sent the callback is beeing called, the msdn documentation was a bit misleading stating: "The EndReceive method will block until data is available" this is true, but if the callback isn't called the EndReceive is neither :/. How can I detect an interuption of the connection then?

Comment: If you call EndReceive before data is available, EndReceive blocks until data is available. But, since the callback is only called when data is available, you never call EndReceive before data is available. You can detect an interruption to the connection only by *sending* data (which will fail if the connection was interrupted).

Comment: Not true. 0 bytes receive means that the connection have been closed by remote peer. Only time it will ***not*** be detected is if TCP can't close the connection properly (network failures and such)

Comment: Googlers: Do note that *some* protocols require you to end a packet with a specific character (eg. newline). Do check up on this, as I was stuck not realizing this for quite a bit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, do not ignore if `EndRecieve` returns 0 bytes. It means that the connection have been closed by the remote end point.

Are you sure that the remote endpoint have sent something to you? My bet is that that is not the case.

I've done quite a few socket applications and I have **never** had any problems with the callback not being called.

It's also very important that you handle exceptions in callback methods. Not doing so will make your application crash when an exception is being thrown.

Comment: the code in my question was only sample code to reproduce the issue, i always handle exceptions inside the callback as well as handling CompletedSynchronously. Thanks for the explanation regarding 0 bytes :)